# Question regarding texture mapping sampling

Tags: texture, sampling, mapping

I am new to computer graphics and have taken up a course in my university on computer graphics. Need help regarding a question as I could not find any relevant resource on the internet so hoping the reddit community can help me with the solution. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undersampling or oversampling occur when an image is projected to a different resolution.

**Untersampling:**
The texture (4x4 pixels) is projected on e.g. 3x3 pixels, see figure 1.
As you can see, the first white stripe is no longer visible because it is between two pixels.

**Oversampling:**
The texture (4x4 pixels) is projected to e.g. 9x9 pixels, see Figure 1.
The image is pixelated because too many pixels fall on each stripe.
When using a LINEAR interpolation sampler, the pixels which are between two stripes will become grey (interpolated color value).

[image]

**Figure1:** Example of under and oversampling.

Comment: thanks a lot for providing me with an answer. Helped a lot and clarified a lot of further concepts.